# How does a popover respond on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, popover

A suggestion/inquiry was made that a div on the website be made into a popover (the hover over) kind.   But how does this functionality occur on a mobile version of the site.  According to the twitter bootstrap [page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers), it has three trigger options: `trigger    string  'hover' how tooltip is triggered - hover | focus | manual`   How would these occur?:

- Hover
- Focus
- Manual

$('#example').popover(options)

I dont have a readily available tablet or mobile device to test, and the behavior is not well documented for this type of viewing/access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover` will trigger when the user clicks on `#example`.  "Manual" will show up since you are personally showing or hiding it in JavaScript.

Comment: There is no change in how focus works.  If an element would have had focus on a desktop it still will on mobile.  Compatibility can be found on http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html